# Though I could noticed or I could noticed though

Tags: conjunctions, word-order

I am trying to express that I noticed the presence of some files on a phone. Which sentence would be correct:

> I could noticed **though**, on the phone, some files and icons apparently leftovers of the installation in Device storage as:

or

> **Though**, I could noticed on the phone, some files and icons apparently leftovers of the installation in Device storage as:

Comment: Can you tell us why you want to use _could_ in your sentence here?

Comment: If you start with 'though', there is no need to follow it with a comma.

Comment: Tense changes in the auxiliary verb only; not the main verb. E.g., 'can notice' becomes 'could notice' in past tense [not could noticed...:(  ]. Will study becomes would study (not would studied  :(

Comment: I did notice, though, on the phone, that some files and icons apparently were leftover from the installation in Device storage as: [spoken language more than written]

Answer (score 0):

In both sentences, "I could noticed" isn't right.

You could say:

"I could have noticed.."

But from what you said about your intending meaning, you certainly *did* notice so it seems like you just need to remove the word "could" altogether. Both sentences are improved without it.

"I noticed though some files in device storage apparently leftover from the installation"

Comment: I'd be inclined to move the _though_ to the end: _I noticed some files in device storage apparently leftover from the installation, though._

Comment: When "though" appears in the middle or at the end of a sentence, shouldn't it be separated by commas/a comma?